# uploading video to Youtube with API Processing abandoned The video could not be processed error

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to upload a video to YouTube. So my code snipped like that:

```
      var request: any = await Youtube.videos.insert({
            resource: {
                snippet: {
                    title: title
                    , description: description
                }
                , status: {
                    privacyStatus: "private"
                }
            }
            , part: "snippet,status"

            , media: {
                body: fs.createReadStream(file)
            }
        }, (err: any, data: any) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.response.data.error)
            }
            console.log("Video upload to youtube Successfull.");
        });
```

But When I checked My YouTube channel I getting an error as

> Processing abandoned The video could not be processed

[image: YouTube channel ss]

Why Im getting this error? How can I solve this problem? Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it might not be uploading the video itself just the metadata. Try this.

```
const youtube = google.youtube({version: 'v3', auth});
var fileMetadata = {
  'title': title
};
var media = {
  body: fs.createReadStream(file)
};
youtube.videos.insert({
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Video upload to YouTube Successful.");;
  }
});
```